# How to list only JPEG files from root below using the command line?

Tags: shell-script, find, file-command

I am searching for a method to find only JPEG files/
With my limited knowledge of Linux I came to this point:

1. list all paths that exist from root below with `find /`
2. pipe the result into next command and perform the `file` command on each found path with `xargs file`
3. In the result of the `file` command is a JPEG string contained, I thought maybe it would be possible somehow to an IF-statement to filter only the JPEGs: If (JPEG contained in output of file command) {show argument of file}

once more:

```
find / | xargs file | "If statement"
```

Could you please correct me, give me a hint how to perform the task or give a solution?

Comment: Do you have a reason to suspect that some JPEG files don't have a `.jpg` extension (or vice versa)? If not, search by name, as in sam's answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to list files containing a JPEG image regardless of the extension in the filename, you could use `find` + `file` to list the files with mime type `image/jpeg`:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    file --mime-type "$0" | grep -q image/jpeg\$ && printf "$0\n"
' {} \;
```

or

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    mt=$(file --brief --mime-type "$0")
    [ -z "${mt#image/jpeg}" ] && printf "$0\n"
' {} \;
```

Answer (score 7):

As a start, you could print out files with a `.jpg` file extension with:

```
sudo find / -name *.jpg -print
```

See how that behaves, modify to suit, and you can then pipe the output into another function rather than just printout if you'd like. For example, if you want to allow `.JPG` as well:

```
sudo find / -iname "*.jpg"
```

Comment: `*.jpg` should be `"*.jpg"`, or it's expanded by the shell  and won't do what you are trying to do.  The `-print` isn't necessary in this case since nothing else is going on.

Comment: I would recommend: (1) Use `-iname` rather than `-name`, so you'll find `*.JPG`, too. (2) Search for the other extensions that JPEG files sometimes have, like `.jpeg`, `.jpe`, and `.jfif`.

Comment: True the `-print` is redundant in this specific case. This was just an quick place to get him started. I'm not sure about the `"` however, as it returns the same results for me with/without. Maybe you could elucidate the implications.

Comment: You do not need `sudo` unless you are looking for private stuff (in other peoples directories), though you will need a `2>/dev/null`.

Comment: @sam without " quotes the `*.jpg` will match files in your current directory. While there aren't any the pattern will remain `*.jpg` but as soon as you have at least one the pattern will be replaced by the matching list. Quote the pattern to prevent this expansion.

Answer (score 0):

This will print the paths to all files with the mime-type of *image/jpeg*.

```
find / -type f -exec file --no-pad --mime-type {} + 2>/dev/null \
    | awk '$NF == "image/jpeg" {$NF=""; sub(": $", ""); print}'
```

A few things to note:

- use `-exec command {} +` instead of `-exec command {} \;` so as to only call `file` once (instead of once for every file)
- use the `--no-pad` option to ensure `file`'s output is in a consistent format (to make parsing it easier)
- use `2>/dev/null` to suppress stderr of `find`, only necessary because running the command from `/` will result in numerous 'Permission denied' errors that will clutter the console