# how to move all files from a pipe into a directory ?

Tags: shell, command-line, xargs, file-command

I performed a file-command on all elements in my Desktop directory:

```
~/Desktop > file *
```

then I grepped all the lines who have the string "image" in the description:

```
~/Desktop > file * | grep "image"
```

then I cut out only the file-name from the each line:

```
~/Desktop> file * | grep "image" | cut -d: -f1
```

From this step on, I do not know how to move all obtained filenames into one directory, I tried xargs, but I think I have a wrong understanding of it:

```
~/Desktop> file * | grep "image" | cut -d: -f1 | xargs mv {} ./dirk
```

Comment: You just [slightly modify the `grep` and replace the `printf` here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185816) with the proper `mv` command.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `--target-directory` option to `mv`.

Comment: ikigai@ikigai-SATELLITE-L50D-B ~/Desktop $ file * | grep "image" | cut -d: -f1 | mv -t ./dirk
mv: missing file operand
Try 'mv --help' for more information.

Comment: You'll still need xargs.

Comment: i am at a loss,  i tried different permutations like ...| xargs mv -t {} ./dirk   with and without {} and so on...

Comment: I don't have time to try, but it should be something like ...| xargs mv -t ./dirk

Comment: you also need `-d '\n'` option with `xargs` to use newlines as the delimiter, otherwise xargs will treat filenames with space(s) in them as two (or more) filenames.  `-r` aka `--no-run-if-empty` is also useful in case there are no matching filenames.  e.g. `... | xargs -r -d '\n' mv -t ./dirk`.    Also, you should edit your answer to say more than just "look at the --target-directory option", you should explain what it does and why it's worth using in this situation.  Otherwise, it's a correct answer, the lack of explanation is the only reason I haven't upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

`{}` is not meaningful to `xargs` unless you pass the deprecated `-i` option or use `-I {}`.

```
file * | grep "image" | cut -d: -f1 | xargs -I {} mv {} ./dirk
```

This only works if your file names don't contain any special characters (`:\"'` or newline or an initial `-`; spaces work with `xargs -I`). This also includes filenames that contain `images` even though they aren't images. This includes files that the `file` command describes as “image” such as “disk image”, not just images as in pictures.

A more reliable (but not perfect) way to filter files whose content is a picture is to use `file -i` and look for files described as `FILENAME: image/TYPE`. The snippet below also converts quote characters that confuse some versions of `xargs`¹.

```
file -i ./* |
sed -n -e 's/["'\''\\]/\\&/' -e 's/: *image\/[^:]*$//p' |
xargs -I {} mv {} ./dirk
```

With reasonably recent versions of the GNU utilities (i.e. non-embedded Linux system or Cygwin), you can use null-separated lists to make the processing reliable and slightly faster.

```
file -0i ./* |
sed -z -e 's/: *image\/[^:]*$//p' |
xargs -0 mv -t ./dirk
```

Another approach, which has the benefit of working even if `file *` fails due to the command line length limit, is to use a loop or `find` to iterate over the files.

```
for x in ./*; do
  if [ -n "$(file -i "$x" | sed -n '$/: *image\/[^:]*$/ p')" ]; then
    mv "$x" ./dirk
  fi
done
```

¹  <sub>POSIX says that `-I` disables `xargs`'s quote processing, but this is not the case in the GNU version as of findutils 4.4.2.</sub>